# SQL query to remove everything after a comma in varchar string values in a column

Tags: sql, database, dolt

I created a database for addresses, however, I made a mistake of concatenating the unit number with the road address which happened to include the unit number as well. So now, the unit number is repeated in some rows.

```
+----------------------------+---------------+
| physical_address           | city          |
+----------------------------+---------------+
| 1 AGATE COURT              | New York City |
| 1 ANGELAS PLACE, 1A, 1A    | New York City |
| 1 ARLINGTON COURT          | New York City |
| 1 AVENUE J                 | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 10M, 10M | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11B, 11B | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11V, 11V | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 12H, 12H | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 14S, 14S | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 15B, 15B | New York City |
+----------------------------+---------------+
```

So if you look in the table above in the last 6 records, in the `physical_address` column, the unit numbers like `10M`, `11B`, `11V` etc are repeated.

Is there any query I can run to remove everything after the last `,` in each row? The type is `varchar` for the column if that helps. Also, keeping in mind that some addresses don't have any `,` in them.

**EDIT** what I have tried:

```
UPDATE sales
SET MyAddress = LEFT(MyAddress, CHARINDEX(',', MyAddress) - 1)
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', MyAddress) > 0
```

This unfortunately removes everything after the first comma, not the last.

This is on a database named [Dolt](https://docs.dolthub.com/introduction/what-is-dolt)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using a MySQL database

Comment: there is a list of [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) available, with a short description of what they do. Which one did you try ?

Comment: @Luuk I edited the post to include the query that came closest. It was removing all after the first comma though, not the last.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Comment: `CHARINDEX` is not in the list of MySQL string function, i mentioned earlier..

Comment: @Luuk so I am actually running these queries in a software called Dolt from Dolthub. I have been it just has a >> dolt sql -q "<insert query here>" interface and so far I have been running MySQL queries and it has been working fine. The query i posted above, I found from an old SO post which now I am realizing is actually a SQLServer post. Otherwise I don't know what exactly Dolt is using, but I have been running MySQL queries because that is the format I know.

Answer (score 1):

This works in MySQL, (but not in Dolt!).

Dolt claims:

> Dolt's goal is to be compliant with the MySQL dialect, with every
> query and statement that works in MySQL behaving identically in Dolt.

But there is no info with which version of mysql this compatibility is, and most things do not work correct (which is the conclusion from a small test using Dolt version 0.35.3)

Anyway, when using MySQL, this can be done:
[DBFIDDLE for the MySQL solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9fc81ba2374c69b7c7b2ffa2d76b7f4)

```
UPDATE Table1
SET physical_address = REGEXP_REPLACE(physical_address,'(,[^,]*),[^,]*','$1')
```

EDIT: (Because it always *starts working* when you say that it will never work):

Below is a session in Dolt, which seems to work, despite the red-**X** in the list of functions near [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.dolthub.com/reference/sql/support/expressions-functions-operators)

```
D:\dolt-windows-amd64\bin>dolt sql-client -P 3307
# Welcome to the Dolt MySQL client.
# Statements must be terminated with ';'.
# "exit" or "quit" (or Ctrl-D) to exit.
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test;
mysql> use test;
mysql> CREATE TABLE Table1 (physical_address varchar(100),city varchar(100));
mysql> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
    ->
    -> ('1 AGATE COURT              ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 ANGELAS PLACE, 1A, 1A    ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 ARLINGTON COURT          ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 AVENUE J                 ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 10M, 10M ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11B, 11B ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11V, 11V ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 12H, 12H ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 14S, 14S ','New York City'),
    -> ('1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 15B, 15B ','New York City');
mysql> SELECT * FROM Table1;
+-----------------------------+---------------+
| physical_address            | city          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 1 ANGELAS PLACE, 1A, 1A     | New York City |
| 1 ARLINGTON COURT           | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11B, 11B  | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 12H, 12H  | New York City |
| 1 AVENUE J                  | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 14S, 14S  | New York City |
| 1 AGATE COURT               | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11V, 11V  | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 10M, 10M  | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 15B, 15B  | New York City |
+-----------------------------+---------------+
mysql> UPDATE Table1  SET physical_address = REGEXP_REPLACE(physical_address,'(,[^,]*),[^,]*','$1')
    -> ;
mysql> SELECT * FROM Table1;
+-----------------------------+---------------+
| physical_address            | city          |
+-----------------------------+---------------+
| 1 ANGELAS PLACE, 1A         | New York City |
| 1 ARLINGTON COURT           | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 10M       | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11B       | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 14S       | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 15B       | New York City |
| 1 AVENUE J                  | New York City |
| 1 AGATE COURT               | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 11V       | New York City |
| 1 BAY CLUB DRIVE, 12H       | New York City |
+-----------------------------+---------------+
mysql>
```

P.S. I still do no like seeing a `mysql>` prompt ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    column_name,
    ',',
    LENGTH(column_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_name, ',', ''))
);
```

Comment: So looking at your query, it should work, but when I run it on the full table it gives me an error. I had not included the rest of the columns, but here is a gist with all the columns in the table and sample data.
https://gist.github.com/vaMuchenje/926b71d7290ca187af73cfb30422b462
When I run the query, it gives me an error saying: 
`duplicate primary key given: ["NY","",2021-03-02 00:00:00]` . The column I am targeting is physical_address.

Comment: you should have provided the complete table definition before complaining about `duplicate primary key`....